# Fully disconnected GIS field data collection options

Tags: android, ios, mobile, gis

I'm looking for recommendations for a disconnected GIS field data collection system that can satisfy the following conditions:

1. map-based data collection app can work on iOS and Android (data
   would likely be only points but may include lines)
2. can export the data to ESRI-friendly format (shapefile or geodatabase)
3. customizable data collection forms, preferably with skip logic abilities
4. can add own (vector) layers to the base map and symbolize appropriately
5. can collect data in a fully disconnected environment
6. can compile data collected from multiple data collection devices into one database/data layer
7. can compile, view and edit the collected data while still disconnected and in the field (ie. via a laptop).

The workflow would be as follows:

1. Field workers would go into the field with a laptop and several tablets (iPad or Android) for field work. They would be in a completely disconnected environment.
2. Multiple tablets would be collecting field data and upload the data to the laptop, where it can be visualized and new maps deployed ad hoc (ie. NO SYNCING TO THE CLOUD).
3. Once the workers are back in the office, they can export the data into shapefile or geodatabase format for use in ArcGIS.

Ideally, the solution would be very ESRI-friendly but primarily, it just has to support the workflow.

So far, I've looked at:

- CartoPac
- GIS Cloud MDC
- Collector for ArcGIS
- Garafa GIS Pro
- Strabo
- CartoPro
- FieldMove

Any suggestions?